# Subir una imagen por Ajax y CI

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Quiero saber si esta bien declarado o seteado mi `JQuery`.

En la parte de captura lo capturo por el `.val()` nose si estará mal o bien,
por que al momento de grabar dice que no e seleccionado ninguna imagen

**MTML :**

```
    <div class="row">
                     <label align="center" class="control-label col-md-12">Imagen</label>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                         <div class="form-group">
                           <div id="form_derivacion" class="form-group col-sm-12">
                              <input id="foto_empleado" name="foto_empleado" type="file" data-show-upload="false" class="file"  required="true" accept="image/*">
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
  </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
function guardar_compra() {

    var numero_compra = $('#numero_compra').val();
    var id_proveedor = $('#id_proveedor').val();
    var monto_total = $('#monto_total').val();
    var fecha_compra = $('#fecha_compra').val();
    var foto_empleado = $('#foto_empleado').val();

        var dataString = 'numero_compra=' + numero_compra
                + '&id_proveedor=' + id_proveedor
                + '&monto_total=' + monto_total
                + '&fecha_compra=' + fecha_compra
                + '&foto_empleado=' + foto_empleado;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: baseurl + 'Compras/guardar_compra',
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                var resultado = $.trim(result);
                if (resultado == 1) {
                    $("#modal_form_producto").modal('hide');
                    $('#notificacion').modal('show');
                    $('#msg_respuesta').html("<strong><FONT color='#1b5e20' SIZE=6>Producto Guardado</FONT>");
                    limpiar();
                    reload_tabla_pagos();
                } else {
                    alert("Error!" + result);
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Este es mi controlador:**

```
public function guardar_compra() {
        $numero_compra = $this->input->post('numero_compra');
        $id_proveedor = $this->input->post('id_proveedor');
        $monto_total = $this->input->post('monto_total');
        $fecha_compra = $this->input->post('fecha_compra');
        $config = [
            "upload_path" => "./assets/images",
            'allowed_types' => "png|jpg"
        ];

        $this->load->library("upload", $config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('foto_empleado')) {
            $data = array("upload_data" => $this->upload->data());
            $datos = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
            if ($this->compras->guardar_compra($numero_compra, $id_proveedor, $monto_total, $fecha_compra, $datos) == true)
                echo "exito";
            else
                echo "error";
        }
        else {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
```

**MI MODELO:**

```
public function guardar_compra() {
        $numero_compra = $this->input->post('numero_compra');
        $id_proveedor = $this->input->post('id_proveedor');
        $monto_total = $this->input->post('monto_total');
        $fecha_compra = $this->input->post('fecha_compra');
        $config = [
            "upload_path" => "./dist/img/compras",
            'allowed_types' => "png|jpg"
        ];

        $this->load->library("upload", $config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
            $data = array("upload_data" => $this->upload->data());
            $datos = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
            if ($this->compras->guardar_compra($numero_compra, $id_proveedor, $monto_total, $fecha_compra, $datos) == true)
                echo "exito";
            else
                echo "error";
        }
        else {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para hacer upload de archivos no es tan directo como enviar una variable.

Este es un ejemplo de como mandar el archivo usando FormData() que tomé de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload). Fijate la respuesta de @pedrozopayares que tiene menos complejidad para implementar. En la misma respuesta muestra el código php para recibir el archivo.

**EDICIÓN 1**

Para subir el resto de los campos se agregan al formData.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);

formData.append('numero_compra', numero_compra);
formData.append('id_proveedor', id_proveedor);
formData.append('monto_total', monto_total);
formData.append('fecha_compra', fecha_compra);

$.ajax({
       url : 'upload.php',
       type : 'POST',
       data : formData,
       processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
       contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
       success : function(data) {
           console.log(data);
           alert(data);
       }
});
```

Comment: Una consulta cuando lo paso solo, si funciona, pero cuando lo paso con otro parámetro es decir con los demás datos capturados con .val, y concatenados en la variable dataString ya no funciona solo funciona cuando le mando la foto sola :c

Comment: Como estás agregando los otros datos?  debería ser formData.append('nombreVariable', valor); antes de la llamada al ajax.

Comment: Observa mi jquery por favor ahi hago la carga de esos inputs

Comment: Fijate si funciona lo que agregué.

Comment: Muchas gracias muchas gracias, aunque hay otro problema sube todo pero no gurda el nombre en la BD :c

Comment: Puse mi modelo :c en la pregunta

Comment: No lo veo muy claro. El controlador y el modelo parecen estar llamando a guardar_compras(..) con parametros similares. Pero la verdad no se que hace esa función del objeto compras. Fijate que hace esa función si contempla el guardado del nombre del archivo y hace un print o log de los valores que le estás pasando a ver si tienen el contenido esperado.